# how to convert multiple images into streams and displaying it i a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a folder named "images" i want to convert all the images in that folder in to streams and display it in a jsp page is that possible if so tell me how to do it.currently i can convert a single image in to stream using the following code

```
String filename=request.getParameter("source1");   
String str="C:\\nambi\\"+"new";
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(str);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(bytes);
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: why do you want to stream multiple images at a time? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i am speaking about converting multiple files from a specific folder int o streams i don't think it matches the one you said??if so can u explain me how?

Comment: i need to display all the images from a specific folder in a jsp page i want it to achieve it using streams so that i can upload and view the images from anywhere in my network

Comment: It's explained at [Java Ranch -Multiple Files in an InputStream](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378485/java/java/Multiple-Files-InputStream) along with working example.

Comment: You want to display all images in JSP page ?

Comment: jsp or html anything is fine

Comment: Normally, you would do this using one JSP/HTML file, with `img` tags for each image in your folder, and one Servlet (or similar, you could use JSP) that serves images for the URLs found in the `src` attribute of the `img` tags. Are you sure you want multiple images in a single stream?

Comment: thank you guys my program is working now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SequenceInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html).

> A SequenceInputStream represents the logical concatenation of other input streams. It starts out with an ordered collection of input streams and reads from the first one until end of file is reached, whereupon it reads from the second one, and so on, until end of file is reached on the last of the contained input streams

Here is an [example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-a-sequenceinputstream-to-connect-several-fileinputstreams.html) and [one more](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/io/catstreams.html)

sample code directly form above link:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SequenceInputStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("testfile1.txt");
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("testfile2.txt");
        FileInputStream fis3 = new FileInputStream("testfile3.txt");

        Vector<InputStream> inputStreams = new Vector<InputStream>();
        inputStreams.add(fis1);
        inputStreams.add(fis2);
        inputStreams.add(fis3);

        Enumeration<InputStream> enu = inputStreams.elements();
        SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(enu);

        int oneByte;
        while ((oneByte = sis.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.write(oneByte);
        }
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
```